# failed to display state value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got blank using getInitialState, must be something is wrong but I don't know where.

```
var counter = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  render() {
    return(
      <p>value of my counter is: {this.state.count}</p>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <counter />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b9bu3ssz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component should be `Counter`, not `counter`

```
var Counter = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  render() {
    return <p>value of my counter is: {this.state.count}</p>
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```